# Is there a way to put lines on a vector?

Tags: java, regex, archive

I have a problem, I'm making a simple program in Java that reads a regular expression like this in a txt file:

```
Name:{[A-z][0-9]}
Phone:{[0-9]}
```

but I'm looking a way to split the name of the regex and put it on a vector:

```
(0) [Name:]
(1) [Phone:]
```

and another vector that it contents the regular expression like this:

```
(0) [[A-z][0-9]]
(1) [[0-9]]
```

The principal idea is splitting the name of the regex and the regex on separated vectors by line of the txt archive, but the problem is that is a **n** number of expressions on the txt file.

Is there an example or something?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want a `Vector` specifically? This seems like a better job for a `Map`.

Comment: seems to be a good idea, but I want a vector because I will do another things with the regex especifically, I will later transform the regex to a java regex in the same position of the vector. Thank you

Comment: You probably don't want to be changing the type of values of an existing vector (since that way you lose type safety), but instead creating a new one with the correct type. If you do that then using a Map works just as well. I've added an example to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing two parallel vectors, I'd recommend using a `Map` data structure for this purpose. If you need to preserve the order of elements from the file for some reason, you can use a `LinkedHashMap`. For example:

```
Map<String, String> regexesByName = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (String line : linesFromFile) {
  int index = line.indexOf(':');
  if (index < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot parse: " + line);
  }
  String name = line.substring(0, index);
  String regex = line.substring(index + 1);
  regexesByName.put(name, regex);
}
```

Then to enumerate all the name/regex pairs, you can do:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : regexesByName.entrySet()) {
  // entry.getKey() is the name, entry.getValue() is the regex
}
```

And to look up the regex for a given name, just do:

```
String regex = regexesByName.get(name);
```

If what you want is to later convert the regexes into compiled `Pattern` objects, that's easily doable as well:

```
Map<String, Pattern> compiledRegexesByName = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : regexesByName.entrySet()) {
  compiledRegexesByName.put(
      entry.getKey(), Pattern.compile(entry.getValue()));
}
```